# Cannot read a bestglm object after writing it with dput

Tags: r

I am trying to use bestglm on a logistic regression model fitting a smaller sample of my data (100x25) matrix (originaly 250kx40).
I run it in BATCH mode. and I wish to write the bestglm models to a file.

```
dput(test2,file="test2.txt",control=c("keepNA","keepInteger","showAttributes"))
t2<-dget(file="test2.txt")
Error in UseMethod("family") : 
  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is something in the `dput`'ing of the `bestglm` that isn't right.  If you simply dput to the console, copy+paste it back in to a new object, it will fail with the same error.

It may be a bug and you may want to reach out to the package maintainer(s).
In the meantime, try using `saveRDS` and `readRDS`:

```
saveRDS(test2, file="test2.rds")

t2 <- readRDS("test2.rds")
```